# Need help with MPD

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hardware, mpd

i'm running MPD (v0.21.20) on an Ubuntu box and using ncmpcpp client on the same machine. The machine has working sound as I am using it for other GUI applications.

Here is an extract of mpd.conf that seems problematic to me:

```
    audio_output {
    type        "alsa"
    name        "My ALSA Device"
#   device      "hw:0,0"    # optional
#   device "iec958:CARD=Intel,DEV=0"
    mixer_type      "software"      # optional
#   mixer_device    "default"   # optional
#   mixer_control   "PCM"       # optional
#   mixer_index "0"     # optional
}
#

#audio_output {
#   type        "pulse"
#   name        "My Pulse Output"
#   server      "127.0.0.1"     # optional
#   mixer_type      "software"
#   device "iec958:CARD=1,DEV=1"
#   mixer_control   "PCM"
#   sink        "remote_server_sink"    # optional
#}
```

When I select ALSA, the WAV file starts playing in ncmpcpp but produces no sound.

```
Nov 10 17:51 : avahi: Service 'Music Player @ mServer' successfully established.
Nov 10 17:51 : client: [0] opened from 127.0.0.1:44676
Nov 10 17:52 : player: played "1.wav"
```

But when I select PULSE, the ncmpcpp just stay paused the whole time:

```
Nov 10 17:50 : client: [0] opened from 127.0.0.1:44670
Nov 10 17:50 : avahi: Service 'Music Player @ mServer' successfully established.
Nov 10 17:50 : exception: Failed to open "My Pulse Output" (pulse)
Nov 10 17:50 : exception: nested: failed to connect: Connection refused
Nov 10 17:50 : exception: Failed to open "My Pulse Output" (pulse)
Nov 10 17:50 : exception: nested: failed to connect: Connection refused
```

Here is the output of aplay -l command showing all playback hardware devices:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: AD1984A Analog [AD1984A Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 2: AD1984A Alt Analog [AD1984A Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: AUDIO [USB  AUDIO], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

And here is the output of mpd --stderr --no-daemon --verbose command which does not seem to show any error that might explain lack of sound:

```
config_file: loading file /etc/mpd.conf
path: SetFSCharset: fs charset is:
libsamplerate: libsamplerate converter 'Fastest Sinc Interpolator'
vorbis: Xiph.Org libVorbis 1.3.6
opus: libopus 1.3.1
sndfile: libsndfile-1.0.28
adplug: adplug 2.3.1
simple_db: reading DB
curl: version 7.68.0
curl: with GnuTLS/3.6.13
avahi: Initializing interface
exception: RTIOThread could not get realtime scheduling, continuing anyway: sched_setscheduler failed: Operation not permitted
avahi: Client changed to state 2
avahi: Client is RUNNING
avahi: Registering service _mpd._tcp/Music Player @ mServer
avahi: Service group changed to state 0
avahi: Service group is UNCOMMITED
state_file: Loading state file /var/lib/mpd/state
playlist: play 0:"1.wav"
decoder_thread: probing plugin sndfile
inotify: initializing inotify
decoder: audio_format=8000:16:2, seekable=true
inotify: watching music directory
exception: OutputThread could not get realtime scheduling, continuing anyway: sched_setscheduler failed: Operation not permitted
avahi: Service group changed to state 1
avahi: Service group is REGISTERING
playlist: queue song 0:"1.wav"
decoder_thread: probing plugin sndfile
decoder: audio_format=8000:16:2, seekable=true
client: [0] opened from 127.0.0.1:44658
client: [0] process command "status"
client: [0] command returned 0
client: [0] process command "plchanges "0""
client: [0] command returned 0
client: [0] process command "outputs"
client: [0] command returned 0
client: [0] process command "decoders"
client: [0] command returned 0
client: [0] process command "outputs"
client: [0] command returned 0
client: [0] process command "outputs"
client: [0] command returned 0
client: [0] process command "idle"
client: [0] command returned 1
avahi: Service group changed to state 2
avahi: Service 'Music Player @ mServer' successfully established.
```

At this stage I am really clueless about where to look for further troubleshooting to get the sound working with MPD, so any pointers will be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this one!

While looking at the output of aplay -l noticed that USB speakers are on card#1, so changed line

device      "hw:0,0"

to device      "hw:1,0"

And it started working!!!